# Discord.py | Update channel name on_member_join

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to **update a channel name** when a member **join/quit** the server.
I have a statistics channel, where the member count is displayed.

I thought I'd create a function, where it gets the channel from the ID, then counts the server members, and finally changes the channel name with the right member count.

**base.py**

This is my function inside the file base.py
Also in this file I handle the events on_member_join / on_member_remove. So I was wondering how to invoke the refresh() function when a user enters or leaves.

```
class base(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @client.command()
    async def refresh(self, ctx):
        stats_channel = client.get_channel(1234567890)
        membri = len(ctx.guild.members)
        await stats_channel.edit(name=' Users: {}'.format(membri))
```

Once I've defined the refresh function, I try to invoke it when a user enters

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):

        await self.refresh()

        print("Other stuff")
```

But once a member enters the server, **this error occurs**:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\Bot\comandi\base.py", line 33, in on_member_join
    await self.refresh()
  File "C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 372, in __call__
    return await self.callback(self.cog, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: refresh() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

I tried a few ways to try to fix it, but without success.

Comment: As seen in the signature for `refresh`, it takes a `ctx` (Context) argument, just like any other Cog (or non-Cog) command. I *think* that a Member object (which you are given in the `on_member_join` handler) passes the same stuff that's expected. You might be able to get away with calling `self.refresh(member)`.

Comment: You will get away with doing that, but its bad practice and might confuse you and others looking at your code later.

Comment: Not necessarily, since "Context" is a loose object type to begin with, if I recall. It is an abstract representation of multiple different possible object types.

*Edit: I might be thinking of Snowflake, or something else...*

Comment: At any rate, I agree with your answer -- if it's not actually a command, then don't frame it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in many ways, first of all. Why is refresh a client command? Do you want users to invoke it manually? If yes, set a default value for ctx.

```py
@client.command()
async def refresh(self, ctx = None):
   #other stuff
   if ctx is not None:
        await ctx.send('refreshed member count')
```

or if you don't need it as a command

```py
async def refresh(self): #no client.command() decorator
   #do stuff here
```

Comment: My intention is to edit the name automatically. Anyway I have already tried, I put @ client.command because it did not find ctx, and I know it is a wrong thing

Comment: Just remove ctx, why have you added ctx.

Comment: It works, thank you.
I added ctx because i copied some lines from another function, that create the stats category and channel

Answer (score -1):

**Don't**

Do not update the channel name every single time a member joins the server. Why?

Discord has a high ratelimit for the amount of time you can change a channel name which is 2 times per 10 minutes. Higher than 2 times will get you ratelimited. This is to completely remove counter bots like yours.

**Do**

If you still want to do this, instead of updating every time on_member_join event triggers, you can check the number of members on the server and change the channel name at an interval, preferably every 30 minutes or an hour.

You can use the `tasks.loop` decorator to trigger a function at an interval. Which is provided by the library. [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop)

Here a solution that you should do, instead of using on_member_join event.

```py
# Define a variable to store the old amount.
old_amount = 0
@tasks.loop(minutes=30)
async def member_checker():
    # Get the guild object
    guild = bot.get_guild(YOUR_GUILD_ID)
    # Check if it's not the same, if it is, update the channel.
    if old_amount != guild.member_count:
       # Update the old amount, and update your channel.
       old_amount = guild.member_count
       your_channel = guild.get_channel(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID)
       await your_channel.edit(name=guild.member_count)

# This function is triggered before the loop occur
@member_checker.before_loop
async def before_looping_occur():
    # You would also need this to not let the loop run before
    # on ready occur, this is to avoid bot.get_guild returns None
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
# Start this task somewhere
member_checker.start()
```

Comment: I tried, I initially put member_checker.start() inside the on_member_join, but it didn't work.
Then I decided to put member_checker.start() inside a simple "while True" but it gets stuck in the before_looping_occur

Comment: Please actually read the documentation. member_checker.start() is supposed to call once. Don't put it inside on_member_join, only call this method once. You can literally just put this when you launch the bot right under the bot declaration.

Comment: the docs at Discord says the rate limit is 50 requests per sec, doesn't matter which request you call, just a global rate limit and that's it